# Get the state of the assets and participants using transaction id

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I created REST API from the steps given at

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html

While trying to fetch history of transaction using GET /system/historian.It returns information like,

```
{
   "$class": "org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord",
   "transactionId": "0dfaf7e32a4d862f3e6458ac618ed1606e588ed73bec1024700b39039031d16a",
   "transactionType": "org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddParticipant",
   "transactionInvoked": "resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddParticipant#0dfaf7e32a4d862f3e6458ac618ed1606e588ed73bec1024700b39039031d16a",
   "participantInvoking": "resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin#admin",
   "identityUsed": "resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.Identity#9611e1e7eaf775ec3ab15735f47d241c818367c520006ae88fea7c3afb4ec9c2",
   "eventsEmitted": [],
   "transactionTimestamp": "2018-04-23T07:09:27.979Z"
}
```

It not returning any information about participants and assets.

I want know the state of the asset or participant at particular transaction.How can I get this? Is there any method/process to get the detail by transaction id?

Answer (score 0):

You can get details of the Participant you added by writing a Query to retrieve "System" transactions with a type AddParticipant, derived from the JSON you shared above: 
`"transactionType": "org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddParticipant"`

If you complete the [Queries tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/queries), then circle back to this and add this new query you should have the information you are looking for.

```
query a2 {
  description: "System Transaction AddParticipant"
  statement:
      SELECT org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddParticipant
}
```

You can create a similar query for the AddAsset system transaction.

(Looking at the Historian and the System Transactions, you are looking at the data at a particular point in time - which could well be different from the *current state*.  I only mention this because of your question title where you mention 'Get the state'.)